# EasyUI panel-header doesn't fit panel

Tags: php, jquery, css, cakephp-3.0

I use an EasyUI panels, but the panel-header doesn't fit the panel so I can't see the icon for the actions of the panel.
EasyUI creates this result :

```
<div class="panel" style="display: block; width: 400px;">
<div class="panel-header" style="width: 412.222px;">
    <div class="panel-title">Select picture</div>
    <div class="panel-tool">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="icon-plus"></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="icon-reload"></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="foto_panel" style="display: block; width: 402.222px; height: 473.111px;" class="easyui-panel panel-body" title="">
    content of the panel
</div>
```

So, you can see that the width of the header `<div class="panel-header">` excetes the width of the wrapping `<div class="panel">`.

All is made by a PHP-function that returns the html based on this script:

```
    $script="
        $(function(){                               
            var w = 400;
            var h = 500;

            $('#foto_panel').panel({                    
                title: 'Select picture',
                width: w,
                height: h,

                tools:[{
                    iconCls: 'icon-plus',
                    handler: function(){
                    }
                },{
                    iconCls: 'icon-reload',
                    handler: function(){
                        $('#".$combo_id."').combobox('reload','".$url."');
                    }
                }]
            });
        });";
```

UPDATE:

I found that some properties (like padding: 0px e.g.) in the css is fooling around with the EasyUI scripts. 
What needs to be changed/commented for EasyUI is working properly.

Thanks.

**solved**

Comment: Please post solutions as actual answers and accept them later, so that questions appear resolved for future readers - thanks!

Comment: Unfortunaly, it's not solved. I noticed that basicly all works well when the stylesheets are disabled, but then I miss some functionalities and the layout.

Comment: I'm trying to find  out which parts of the css-files are conflicting.

Comment: I detected several incompabilities between Easui.CSS and Base.CSS (included in cakePHP) I commented out all .padding.